# Bibtex problem in file with no bibliography

Tags: tables, bibtex, texmaker

I'm trying to make a file with a very simple table, but this error keeps happening even in the simplest of table files, for example, when i try to compile the following code this is the result:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm}}

this is a very simple table file example & this is another very simple column about tables 

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 23.10.12) The top-level auxiliary file: tabla.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file tabla.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file tabla.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file tabla.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: **How** are you trying to compile? It sounds to me like something in your work pipeline (either make file or maybe your IDE used for TeX) is running automatically `bibtex` when it is not necessary.

Comment: with texmaker and miktex

Comment: TeXmaker is just an editor. It probably allows you to run a whole bunch of different compilation commands. You appear to be using a build recipe which includes an instruction to run `bibtex`. Choose a different recipe.

Comment: thanks, the fast compile always runs bibtex, just selected the fast compile with no bibtex

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by picking the wrong command in the IDE and has been resolved in comments. (The problem wasn't caused by the code in the question.)